# Magento 2: move the top links in the same container as the logo

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, toplinks

I am working on a **Magento 2.1.7** shop. To achieve this, I have created a **child-theme of Magento Blank**.

My top links (above the logo) are:

1. Compare Products
2. Default welcome msg!
3. My Account
4. My Wish List
5. Create an Account
6. Sign In

I need to remove all the links *except*:

1. My Account
2. My Wish List
3. Sign In

I want to **move the 3 links** above on the same block - `<div class="header content"></div>` - as the logo.

The logo will be floated to the *left*, while the 3 links will be floated to the *right*.

What files must I edit to achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you research that for your self?. **remove block**, **xml block magento 2**

Comment: I want to remove My Account My Wish List Sign In Default welcome msg! Create an Account form header

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/148332)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/148332)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Remove Compare Products link:

> Theme_Root/Magento_Catalog/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="true" />
```

2. Remove Default welcome message:

> Theme_Root/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="header" remove="true" />
```

3. Remove Create an Account link:

> Theme_Root/Magento_Customer/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true" />
```

4. Move Top Links to the right container:

> Theme_Root/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<move element="top.links" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo" />
```

After these manipulations you need align blocks logo and links via CSS, with float.

5. Create block with My Wish List:

> Theme_Root/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="header.panel">
    <block name="panel.top.links" class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" after="-">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

> Theme_Root/Magento_Wishlist/layout/default.xml

```
<move element="wish-list-link" destination="panel.top.links" />
```

Write me if you need any help.

Comment: Great, but I want to keep _My Wish List_ at the top, in its initial place. How can I do that?

Comment: I updated my answer. Check it, please

Comment: I want to turn 
`<ul class="clearfix header links">
  <li><a href="/customer/account/">My Account</a></li>
  <li class="authorization-link" data-label="or"><a href="/account/login/">Sign In</a>
  </li>
</ul>`
into 
`<ul class="clearfix header links">
  <li><a href="/customer/account/"><i class="fa fa-user-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 My Account</a></li>
  <li class="authorization-link" data-label="or"><a href="/account/login/"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 Sign In</a>
  </li>
</ul>`
In other words, how do I add icons?

Comment: In first link you can add css class on block via `<argument name="class" xsi:type="string"> ... </argument>` in `Theme_Root/Magento_Customer/layout/default.xml`. In second link you need override `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/account/link/authorization.phtml` in your theme and adjust it.